# Flask circular import issue - import variables from __init__.py into views

Tags: python, flask, python-import, importerror

This is my **project structure**:

```
myproject
    myproject
        __init__.py
        static
        templates
        views
            __init.py__
            home.py
    venv
    myproject.wsgi
    requirements.txt
    setup.py
```

This is my **`__init__.py`**:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, Response, render_template
from myproject.views import home

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="static", static_url_path='/static')
test_string = "Hello World!"

app.register_blueprint(home.home)
```

And this is my **`views/home.py`**:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, Response, Blueprint
import json
import requests
from myproject import test_string

home = Blueprint('home', __name__)

@home.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return(test_string)
```

When I visit the page, I get an error `ImportError: cannot import name test_string`. The Python import system is really confusing and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I suspect this is a circular import issue.

How do I solve this?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you have code in an `__init__.py`, try to avoid writing things in it that can be imported from somewhere else. Think of `__init__.py` as a leaf in a graph regarding imports, it should only import and run stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move, in `__init__.py`, the line `from myproject.views import home` after the line `test_string = "Hello World!"`.

This way Python will be find the test_string name.

To understand circular imports you have to "think like the interpreter", when you execute `__init__.py` the interpreter will:

1. execute line 1 of `__init__.py`
2. execute all the code that this line implies (importing stuff from flask)
3. execute line 2 of `__init__.py`
4. execute line 1 of `views/home.py` (importing only `Blueprint` from flask, for it's the onnly non-already-imported thing)
5. execute lines 2+3 of `views/home.py` (import json and requests)
6. execute line 4 of `views/home.py`
7. go back to *what he executed* in `__init__.py` and search for the name `test_string`

here it raises an error, because *what he executed* do not comprehend `test_string`. If you move the import *after* the execution of `test_string = "Hello World!"` the interpreter will find this name in the namespace.

This is commonly recognized as bad design though, IMHO the best place to store test_string would be a `config.py` file, in which no imports from other project modules are performed, avoiding circulat imports.

Comment: Thank you. This clears up a lot of things. And it works! So the best practice is to move the `test_string` to `config.py` and import it in `views.py`? If I'd need the same `test_string` in multiple views, would importing it in `__init__.py` make sense? Or like @Arne mentioned, I shouldn't put anything in the `__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes, as @Arne mentioned it's better to design a project so your execution starting point (__init__.py in your case) is just an executor of other modules code, and not a "bin" of code that other modules would need. Looking at a project structure, the more the imports are in one direction (from the starting point to the modules and submodules) the better. Avoid bidirectional imports and group shared resources (like your test_string) in a "common" module imported by the others (ie: all your views)